# How do I get the output of executable without using "write" command?

Tags: linux, gfortran

I have a hello world code that is compiled. How do I get the output of the executable in a file instead of printing in the terminal where the program runs. Can it be done without including "write" command in code ?

The executable created is "hello.out" and compiled using "mpif90 hello.f90 -o hello.out"

Comment: How do you write now? Probably you mean "without using an `OPEN` statement"

Answer (score 1):

```
./hello.out > filename
```

If you still want to see the output on the terminal as well you can pipe it to `tee` instead:

```
./hello.out | tee filename
```

This will write the output to the file and to the terminal.